# Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key when locally running MPI application or starting ParaView

Tags: ubuntu, mpi, xauth

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, locally, no remote access or anything. Still, whenever I start up `paraview` from the terminal, or when I run an application that uses MPI (I think it's enough if it calls `MPI_Init()`), then I get the error message
`Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key`

How can I solve this?

MPI implementation: Open MPI 4.0.3

ParaView version: 5.7.0

Comment: btw, it doesn't happen anymore on Ubuntu 21.04.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the `libhwloc` library, which is used by `OpenRTE` (the OpenMPI component) to explore the hardware topology of the node during the launch of parallel processes. When `hwloc_topology_load()` is called, `libhwloc` iterates over all of its available components, which are implemented as plug-ins. One of these components, `gl`, is responsible for gathering information about the system's graphics devices and uses X11 calls like `XOpenDisplay()`, which can generate the error message "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key" if it fails to connect to the X11 server.

In many cases, this gl component is not needed on HPC clusters and can be safely disabled by setting the `HWLOC_COMPONENTS` environment variable to exclude it:

`export HWLOC_COMPONENTS="-gl"`

Answer (score -1):

I find that `rm ~/.Xauthority` and then logging out and back in works.

See the resolution to the xinit error: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/197

More on why the situation arises: https://askubuntu.com/a/300737/1057634

According to the [man pages](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xauth.1.html#files), the ~/.Xauthority file is created automatically when you run a GUI application involving a remote server, and when you ssh using [ssh -X](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1863739) (but if you just ssh you will get an error saying you need a .Xauthority file to be able to connect to the server).

Comment: There is no remote server, I made that clear in the question: "no remote access or anything".
I also don't have an .Xauthority folder.

Comment: I don't have a remote server (remote access or anything) to my machine either. The .Xauthority file is a hidden file not a folder.

Comment: The links you provided are to now eight year old pages. A lot has happened since then, especially regarding ```xauth```. I don't have that program on my machine, and I therefore I also don't have an ```.Xauthority``` file. I've seen that answer before, it's easy to find, but it doesn't apply.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution @RL-S ?

Comment: No, sadly I haven't.